# Find continent of each country using an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, find

I have this array of object:

```
const CONTINENT_MAP = [
  {
    continent: 'Oceania',
    countries: ['Australia', 'Fiji'],
  },
  {
    continent: 'Europe',
    countries: [
      'Anguilla',
      'Aruba',
      'Austria',
      'Azerbaijan',
      'Belgium',
      'Bulgaria',
      'Croatia',
      'Curacao',
      'Cyprus',
      'Denmark',
      'Finland',
      'France',
      'Georgia',
      'Germany',
      'Greece',
      'Italy',
      'Luxembourg',
      'Malta',
      'Monaco',
      'Netherlands',
      'Netherlands Antilles',
      'Norway',
      'Poland',
      'Portugal',
      'Romania',
      'Spain',
      'Sweden',
      'Switzerland',
      'Ukraine',
      'United Kingdom',
    ],
  },
  {
    continent: 'Asia',
    countries: [
      'Bahrain',
      'China',
      'East Timor',
      'India',
      'Indonesia',
      'Iran',
      'Iraq',
      'Israel',
      'Japan',
      'Jordan',
      'Kazakhstan',
      'Myanmar',
      'North Korea',
      'South Korea',
      'Kuwait',
      'Kyrgyzstan',
      'Laos',
      'Malaysia',
      'Oman',
      'Pakistan',
      'Qatar',
      'Russian Federation',
      'Saudi Arabia',
      'Singapore',
      'Taiwan',
      'Thailand',
      'Turkey',
      'Turkmenistan',
      'United Arab Emirates',
      'Uzbekistan',
      'Vietnam',
      'Yemen',
    ],
  },...]
```

And another array:

```
const dataset = [{country: 'Vietnam', color: 'blue'}, {country: 'Matla', color: 'red'}, ...]
```

I want to loop dataset and get the continent of each country. The comparison between country strings must be case insensitive.
So I write this function:

```
export function equalsStringIgnoreCase(str1: string, str2: string) {
  return typeof str1 === 'string' && typeof str2 === 'string'
    ? str1.localeCompare(str2, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }) === 0
    : str1 === str2
}
```

Then, I try this piece of code:

```
const result = dataset.map(value => {
  const continent = CONTINENT_MAP.find(cont => {
    return cont.countries.map(country => {
      return equalsStringIgnoreCase(country, value.country)
    })
    // return continent.countries.includes(value.country) // easy but case sensitive
  })
  return {
    continent: continent.continent,
    country: value.country,
  }
})
```

But I get **Argument of type '(this: void, continent: { continent: string; countries: string[]; }) => boolean[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { continent: string; countries: string[]; }, index: number, obj: { continent: string; countries: string[]; }[]) => boolean'.
  Type 'boolean[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'**.

Comment: The compiler is telling you, correctly, that you're returning an array of booleans instead of a single boolean.  You should use the array's [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method, not its not `map()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be **more efficient and succinct** by first creating a map of countries to continent. This will remove all the needed search and filtering for each country and you will just need to index your map by country.

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do that, here is the code to get the result you want:

```
const countriesToContinent = CONTINENT_MAP.reduce((acc, { continent, countries }) => {
  countries.forEach(country => acc[country.toLocaleLowerCase()] = continent);
  return acc;
}, {});

const dataset = [{country: 'Vietnam', color: 'blue'}, {country: 'Matla', color: 'red'}];

const result = dataset.map(({ country, color }) => ({
    continent: countriesToContinent[country.toLocaleLowerCase()],
    country,
}));
```

And a live example:

```js
const CONTINENT_MAP = [
  {
    continent: 'Oceania',
    countries: ['Australia', 'Fiji'],
  },
  {
    continent: 'Europe',
    countries: [
      'Anguilla',
      'Aruba',
      'Austria',
      'Azerbaijan',
      'Belgium',
      'Bulgaria',
      'Croatia',
      'Curacao',
      'Cyprus',
      'Denmark',
      'Finland',
      'France',
      'Georgia',
      'Germany',
      'Greece',
      'Italy',
      'Luxembourg',
      'Malta',
      'Monaco',
      'Netherlands',
      'Netherlands Antilles',
      'Norway',
      'Poland',
      'Portugal',
      'Romania',
      'Spain',
      'Sweden',
      'Switzerland',
      'Ukraine',
      'United Kingdom',
    ],
  },
  {
    continent: 'Asia',
    countries: [
      'Bahrain',
      'China',
      'East Timor',
      'India',
      'Indonesia',
      'Iran',
      'Iraq',
      'Israel',
      'Japan',
      'Jordan',
      'Kazakhstan',
      'Myanmar',
      'North Korea',
      'South Korea',
      'Kuwait',
      'Kyrgyzstan',
      'Laos',
      'Malaysia',
      'Oman',
      'Pakistan',
      'Qatar',
      'Russian Federation',
      'Saudi Arabia',
      'Singapore',
      'Taiwan',
      'Thailand',
      'Turkey',
      'Turkmenistan',
      'United Arab Emirates',
      'Uzbekistan',
      'Vietnam',
      'Yemen',
    ],
  }
];

const countriesToContinent = CONTINENT_MAP.reduce((acc, { continent, countries }) => {
  countries.forEach(country => acc[country.toLocaleLowerCase()] = continent);
  return acc;
}, {});

const dataset = [{country: 'Vietnam', color: 'blue'}, {country: 'Austria', color: 'red'}];

const result = dataset.map(({ country, color }) => ({
    continent: countriesToContinent[country.toLocaleLowerCase()],
    country,
}));

console.log(result)
```